# Is the weird licensings incompatibility issue mentioned by Stallman still relevant?

Tags: distributions, tex-history, licensing

In a recent [article](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-compatibility.html) on FSF.org

> ** The main license in actual use that isn't reasonably behaved is the license of TeX: if two programs are licensed just the way TeX is, there is no authorized way to distribute a merged version of them.
>
> The TeX license permits distribution of a modified version only in the form of the original version plus a differences file. If A and B are separately released that way, then merged, distributing the merged program as A plus a change file violates the license of B. Distributing this as B plus a change file violates the license of A. Distributing this in any other way violates both licenses.
>
> It is no coincidence that TeX was released in 1982: our community has learned, since then, to write reasonably behaved licenses.

Do modern TeX distribution suffer from this issue, or is that just ancient history these days?

Comment: That is precisely what Knuth intended, to prevent the spread of not-quite-compatible versions of programs that were all *called* TeX. Of course it doesn't fit with Stallman's entrenched views about how the software industry should operate.

Comment: @alephzero Sure: if you look at newer software, though, people use _trademarks_ for the naming, and leave licensing to deal with things it is good at!

Comment: For the LaTeX license there is https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2011-FMi-TUB-tb100mittbach-lppl-history.pdf and hundreds of mails at https://lists.debian.org/debian-legal/2002/07/

Comment: @moewe: I'd like to avoid reading hundreds of mails from 16 years ago...

Comment: You are given a link that helps you understand the current situation and yet you don't want to read.  To sum it up in short: it is complicated.

Comment: @Johannes_B: 1. The first link is fine, I'll read that. 2. On StackExchange sites, and AFAICR, the policy is to prefer information, even if summarized / in short-form, rather than simply referring people to off-site links.

Comment: @einpoklum but basically you are asking for legal advice on current licences, i think this is off topic. the licence on tex is as it was so the situation is unchanged but whether there is an issue or anyone suffers is a matter of opinion so also off topic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm really not asking for legal advice, I'm asking for historical information - whether the licenses were revamped to avoid this situation or whether it was decided to keep them in this vein.

Comment: well in that case no, the licence on tex has not changed in any way. If you want historical information rather than off topic opinion you should phrase it as a question asking if the wording has changed without the highly subjective "weird licence" phrasing you have used.

Comment: If you look at for example `etex.ch` it says explicitly `Programs such as TIE allow the application of several change files to tex.web; the master files tex.web and etex.ch should stay intact.`, which seems to be pretty clear that _several_ `.ch` files could be applied (`tex.web` itself doesn't rule out applying multiple `.ch` files: `The WEB system provides for alterations via an auxiliary file; the master file should stay intact.`). That is done for example for e-upTeX (some big `.ch` files, some small 'glue' ones.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've read Frank Mittelbach's [article](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2011-FMi-TUB-tb100mittbach-lppl-history.pdf) in TUG-Boat and would be quite satisfied with a two-liner answer and a link to it.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That article gave me the answer I wanted, basically.